# When we submit a form, what happened?

Tags: python, django

Actually, I just want to get a very simple web application:

1. a form in a webpage that I can upload a file within some parameters;
2. submit the form when I choose a proper file;
3. do some calculation using these parameters in uploaded file;
4. redirect to a new webpage with the calculation result;
5. display the result in this new webpage.

I use Django 1.10.

**index.html** with `<form>` like this:

```
<form action="/index/result/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type=">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="id_file">Input File:</label>
        {{ form.file }}  <!--from django model-->
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

**result.html** for display result like this:

```
<div id="out">
    <table id="result_display" border="1px" hidden>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
          <!--here will display the value comes from result-->
                <th id="r_name"> {{ result }} </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

my **views.py** like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from forms import UploadFileForm


# Create your views here.
@csrf_exempt
def index_view(request):
    para = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            if cd['file']:
                para = cd.get('file').read().split('\r\n')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Please Input a File!')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is invalid!')
    if para:
        # do some calculation with para
        result = {"name": "NAD"}
        return redirect('result_view', result=result)  # to another view 'result_view'
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})


def result_view(request, result=''):
    if result:
        return render(request, 'result.html', {'result': result})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('no result!')
```

my **urls.py** like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', index_view),
    url(r'^index/result/?(?P<result>.*)/$', result_view, name='result_view'),
]
```

Here are what really confuse me a lot:

**Q1**: There are two places give result url address `<form action="/index/result/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` in index.html and `url(r'^index/result/?(?P<result>.*)/$', result, name='result'),` in urls.py, which one is dominated?

**Q2**: How to pass data (i.e. calculation result) from `index_view` to `result_view`? 
I didn't get `result` in `result_view` function using current method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: urls.py only maps the urls to the views used to render them. When you submit a form to `/index/result/`, Django will try to find a view, that matches the url, in this case `results_view`.

Q2: Instead of passing the result from `index_view` to `result_view`, you should move the whole logic of calculating the result to the `result_view`.

Comment: Q1 is not quite true, because OP has a ? before the `<result>` group, which makes it optional; "/index/result/" *does* match.

Comment: If just use one view function also can display all result, but both webpages `index` and `result` have the same url, so when you refresh webpage, you have to submit again. I don't want to submit form again, I want to redirect  to a different url for `result` page.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks for pointing that out. Fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you enlightened me, I have solved this problem through _moving the logic of calculating the result to the `result_view`_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your form is posting directly to the result view. This means that the calculations that happen on POST in your index view are never called, and the result value is always empty.

Your form should post to just `/index/`, or even better to `{% url "index_view" %}`; and your result view should not make the result value optional.

Comment: if I return "HttpResponse(result)" directly after calculating, I can see result in browser. So result is not empty. But I cannot pass it to result_view.

Comment: Hi, Daniel Roseman, are you still there? Can you please check this question again? I tried a lot of different ways, but it still not work.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying; your form is definitely posting straight to the result view.

Comment: At the beginning, I didn't submit any data, `request.method` not equal to `POST`, so we can see a empty form at the first when we open `http://192.168.1.100:8023/index/`. and `render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})` returned. When I submit form, the data will go to `http://192.168.1.100:8023/index/result` and try to find `result_view` function? So I should receive these data in `result_view` function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what is unclear. You just confirmed what I said; you submit the form to /index/result, so naturally the code that you have in index_view that calculates the value of "result" is not run.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have solved this problem. I should receive input data and calculate at result_view function.